# MS Access automatically fill id in main form when data is entered in subform

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access, I have an unusual relationship set up.  I am showing coordinates of points in a series of polygons.  The polygons don't need any reference data other than an id, but they can each have any number of coordinates.  So I have two tables: Coordinates and Polygons.  Coordinates has fields: coordinateID, x, y, order, PolygonID.  Polygons just has the PolygonID field which is autonumber.

```
Polygons                      Coordinates
--------                      -----------
PolygonID(primary key)--------PolygonID(foreign key)
                              coordinateID(primary key)
                              x
                              y
                              order
```

I've created a form for Polygons with a subform for Coordinates.  I've set up a parent child relationship with referential integrity.

The problem is, Access normally expects the parent table to have some data other than an autonumber field, so it waits for data entry before creating the next record.  I can type the next number in the sequence, and Access creates the record, but if I skip that step and just enter data in the subform, no record is created in the parent table, and I end up with orphaned entries.

Is there a way to force Access to create the parent record when I start entering data in the child table?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple possible issues here...

First, you will want to make sure you are **linking the parent and child forms** together on the `PolygonID` field. This can be done with the SubForm Wizard,

[image]

or through the properties on the subform object.

[image]

The second thing to verify is that you have **actually created a new record** in the parent form before you try to add a record in the subform.

To illustrate this, you can add a `Description` field to the `Polygons` table. Notice that the autonumber field increments to a number when you start editing the description.

[image]

Now if you enter a coordinate value for `x`, the `PolygonID` populates automatically.

[image]

### Update

Normally you would create a parent record first, then add child records. But in this case the OP would like to create the parent record automatically from a new record on the child form ***before*** the parent record actually exists.

It is possible to do this using some VBA code in the child form, but first you need to add at least one additional field to the parent form's table. The following code then fires on the `Form_Dirty` event in the child form which happens as soon as you begin adding a new child form record. It checks for a null ID on the parent form, and if it finds one, it assumes this is a new record on the parent form. From there, it changes a field value on the parent form. This creates the new parent record and pushes the `PolygonID` back down to the child form through the parent/child link.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
    With Me.Parent
        If IsNull(!PolygonID) Then
            ' Change any field to create the parent record
            .Description = "Test"
            ' Save changes on the parent form.
            .Dirty = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Again, this isn't the typical usage scenario for parent/child forms, but it does demonstrate a way to create a related parent record from a child form.

Comment: I don't think I've made myself completely clear.  My relationships are set up correctly.  There is referential integrity and if I fill in the record on the parent form manually, then everything links properly.  The problem is that I want Access to automatically create the record in the parent form when I create the first subform record.  That way I don't have to enter the data manually in the parent form, and it's better for data integrity, because there wouldn't be a risk of myself typing in the wrong number on the parent form.

Comment: @NathanJessee - See the update in my answer for a way to do this.

Comment: Excellent!  I know it's an unusual scenario, but it works exactly as I need it to.

Comment: Slick.  Just what I was looking for.  Slicker than what the devs who wrote Northwinds did.  Humans don't like constraints.  If they want to paste the item description in before the customer name, is that so much to ask?  Worked for me.  PolygonID can be the default ID record key.  The word "Test" doesn't have to be in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you establish Referential Integrity between the tables set up MasterLinkFields and ChildLinkFields of the subform control to hold PolygonID, the foreign key of the subform records will be filled in automatically.

Comment: The problem is normally you have a parent table with several fields and a child form with several fields.  When press the new record button, Access waits until data is entered in the main form to create the new record and assign the new autonumber primary key.  This makes sense in most cases.  My problem is that my parent form only has a primary key with no other fields and that field is automatically assigned, but because there is no data for me to enter, it doesn't create the new record; it waits for me to enter data.

Comment: I can just retype the id that should be there and Access creates the record, but this is error prone, because I could type in the wrong thing.  Semantically the only data to be entered is in the subform, so I need access to create the main form record when the first subform record is being filled in.

Comment: Hmm. A form with only an autonumber field doesn't make sense to me.